# Does it affect performance a lot to use redux state inside a element that is used many times?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom dropdown component to which a can pass a custom dropdown item. The problem is I have a case where I had to give some classes to the dropdown item based on redux store but I can't use it in the main dropdown component because that piece of state is not always used in the custom dropdown, a bad solution would be using the state inside the custom dropdown item but how can I do better because the custom dropdown item will be used a lot inside the custom dropdown component?

```
function CustomDropdown({listItem,onClick,options}){
  let elements = options.map(el=>listItem(el,onClick));
  return (
    <ul>{elements}</ul>
   )
}

function listItem(el,onClick){
  return (
  <li onClick={onClick} className={clsx(someReduxState&&"selected")} >{el}</li>
  )
}

<CustomDropdown onClick={()=>{}} listItem={listItem} options=["1","2","3"] />
```